# 【Rails】本番環境用のフルパスの取得について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

開発環境で[xxx_url]を書くとlocalhostからのフルパスが取得できるのですが、
開発環境で本番環境用のフルパスを取得したいと思っています。

そもそも取得できるのでしょうか。
オプションや他のやり方があれば教えてください。

```
xxx_url => localhost:3000/xxx
yyy_url => honban.com/yyy
```

こんな感じで取得したいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[default_url_options= (ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Base) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/default_url_options%3D) でいかがでしょうか？

[Rails Internationalization (I18n) API — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params)
にあるように、application_controller に記載するか、
より単純に、environments に記載してしまう、という方法もあると思います。

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: "honban.com" }
```